# Store the information in the text files not in the db?

Tags: php, html, css

Hi all  am new to the php ,I try out file handling in php , i.e., storing the information to the text files not in the database .which is basically insert the data to the text files and deleting the data in a file but i am struggling to delete the last records in the text file here is my code anyone much appreciated..

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>
Registration
</title>
<style type="text/css">
table{font-family:calibri;color:black;font-size:11pt,font-style:normal;background-color:white;border-collapse:collapse;border:2px solid navy}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="frnt.js">
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="aqua">
<form name="myform" action="writ.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validation()">
<table border="0px"align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
<th colspan="2" align="center">Registration</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>UserName:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="nme" maxlength='20'>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mail" maxlength='20'>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mobile:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mobile" maxlength='10'>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Education:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="edu" maxlength='10'>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>College:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="clg" maxlength='15' >
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"><input type="reset" value="Reset">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this page redirects to the writ.php and this code is to be

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form method = "post">
        <?php

        $body = $_POST['nme'];
        $body1 = $_POST['mail']; 
        $body2 = $_POST['mobile'];
        $body3 = $_POST['edu'];
        $body4 = $_POST['clg'];
        $file_name = "test.txt";               
        $fp = fopen ($file_name, "a"); 

        fwrite ($fp,"Name:".$body."\r");
        fwrite ($fp,"Email:".$body1."\r");
        fwrite ($fp,"Mobile:".$body2."\r");
        fwrite ($fp,"Education:".$body3."\r");
        fwrite ($fp,"College:".$body4."\r\r");


            if(fwrite)  {
                echo "your data added successfully <br><br>";
                echo "<a href='back .php'>Go back to view your page</a>";
            }

        ?>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And this is deleting whole data's in the text file

```
<?php
$v=filesize("test.txt");
echo "<br />";

$file = fopen("test.txt", "a+");
$d=ftruncate($file,0) or die ('could not open'); 
if($d)  {
echo "deleted the whole data's successfully<br><br>";
echo"<a href='frm.php'>Add data to a file </a><br><br>";
echo"<a href='test.txt'>View the file </a><br><br>";
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Finally i have an problem with the this coding

```
<?php 
$file="test.txt";
$str = fopen("test.txt","r");
$s = fgets($str);

$parts = explode("\r",$s);
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$c=count($parts);
$dd=$c-8;
for($i=$c;$i>$dd;$i--)  {

$content = str_replace($parts[$i],'', $content);
/*$content = str_replace($parts[7],'', $content);
$content = str_replace($parts[8],'', $content);
$content = str_replace($parts[9],'', $content);
$content = str_replace($parts[10],'', $content);
*/
$fh = fopen($file, 'w');
$d=fwrite($fh, $content);
}
//unset($parts[$i],'');
if($d)  {
echo"Last data deleted successfully <br><br>";
}

?>
```

In the above coding i face the problem has when i enter the same email id to the multiple times its store in the text file but when i going to delete the last records in the file the same name of email also deleted !!!!  And how to solve this .
Please help! Much appreciated:)

Comment: your not using a database for this - why?

Comment: Storing user data inside a text file on the actual server posses a somewhat security flaw inside the entire application you are running. 

All it takes is a user to find out a pattern or look hard enough to discover what the name for their text file is, and with a few changes of the URL and the bad guy has got access to all your users information. I would recommend switching to a Database of some kind, they give the administrator easy management aswell as a sense of proper security (if the database is secured properly)

Comment: by this way i am going to store the information in the text file also in the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change `fopen("test.txt", "a")`to `fopen("test.text", "w")` it will delete everything that is inside the txt.
"w" means: Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. (According to [PHP.net fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php))